# Why does as.integer64("") return 0 instead of NA_integer64_?

Tags: r, bit64

Given that the base `as.integer()` coercion of the empty string is `NA` without warning, as in:

```
str( as.integer(c('1234','5678','')) ) # int [1:3] 1234 5678 NA -- no warning
```

I'm struggling to understand why `bit64::as.integer64()` coerces to zero without warning:

```
library('bit64')
str( as.integer64(c('1234','5678','')) ) # integer64 [1:3] 1234 5678 0 -- no warning
```

What's even stranger is to compare:

```
str( as.integer(c('1234','5678','', 'Help me Stack Overflow')) ) 
# int [1:4] 1234 5678 NA NA -- coercion warning
```

with:

```
str( as.integer64(c('1234','5678','', 'Help me Stack Overflow')) ) 
# integer64 [1:4] 1234 5678 0 NA -- no warning
```

My workaround for this fails miserably:

```
asInt64 <- function(s){
  require(bit64)
  ifelse(grepl('^\\d+$',s), as.integer64(s), NA_integer64_)
}
str(asInt64(c('1234','5678','', 'Help me Stack Overflow')) )
# num [1:4] 6.10e-321 2.81e-320 0.00 0.00
# huh?
```

So, I'm asking:

- why does this happen?
- what is the best workaround?

Comment: Maybe because [`strtoll("", ...)`](https://github.com/cran/bit64/blob/master/src/integer64.c#L200) is `0`. Workaround could be to convert these `grepl("\\D|^$", c('1234','5678','', 'Help me Stack Overflow'))` to `NA` afterwards?

Comment: @lukeA you basically answered the question, thanks.  This [reference](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdlib_h/strtoll.php) suggests testing for a conversion error when `strtoll` returns 0, which `as.integer64` isn't quite catching with the `endpointer` logic.  I'm going to try to propose a change, although my C is quite rusty. 
 If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

### Why it happens

As @lukeA's comment points out, the source for `as.integer64.character` is:

```
SEXP as_integer64_character(SEXP x_, SEXP ret_){
  long long i, n = LENGTH(ret_);
  long long * ret = (long long *) REAL(ret_);
  const char * str;
  char * endpointer;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    str = CHAR(STRING_ELT(x_, i)); endpointer = (char *)str; // thanks to Murray Stokely 28.1.2012
    ret[i] = strtoll(str, &endpointer, 10);
    if (*endpointer)
      ret[i] = NA_INTEGER64;
  }
  return ret_;
}
```

and `strtoll("")` returns zero with an error when called on an invalid value such as `""` or `"ABCD"`.  One reference [`strtoll` example](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdlib_h/strtoll.php) handles this like:

```
/* If the result is 0, test for an error */
if (result == 0)
{
    /* If a conversion error occurred, display a message and exit */
    if (errno == EINVAL)
    {
        printf("Conversion error occurred: %d\n", errno);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* If the value provided was out of range, display a warning message */
    if (errno == ERANGE)
        printf("The value provided was out of range\n");
}
```

So what I am trying to figure out now is why `*endpointer` is evaluating to FALSE. (Stay tuned...)

### Workaround

Here's the workaround to mimic the behavior of base `as.integer`:

```
library(bit64)
charToInt64 <- function(s){
  stopifnot( is.character(s) )
  x <- as.integer64(s)
  # as.integer64("") unexpectedly returns zero without warning.  
  # Overwrite this result to return NA without warning, similar to base as.integer("")
  x[s==""] <- NA_integer64_
  # as.integer64("ABC") unexpectedly returns zero without warning.
  # Overwrite this result to return NA with same coercion warning as base as.integer("ABC")
  bad_strings <- grepl('\\D',s) # thanks to @lukeA for the hint
  if( any(bad_strings) ){
    warning('NAs introduced by coercion')
    x[bad_strings] <- NA_integer64_  
  }
  x
}
```

To see that this works:

```
test_string <- c('1234','5678','', 'Help me Stack Overflow')
charToInt64(test_string) # returns int64 [1] 1234 5678 <NA> <NA> with warning
charToInt64(head(test_string,-1)) # returns int64 [1] 1234 5678 <NA> without warning
```