# Override non-default method and avoid recursion

Tags: r, recursion, dispatch, generic-function

What programming principles can help me avoid recursion when using the generic function system to dispatch a modified method that calls the original method?

## Background

I'm not satisfied with the behavior of `bit64::as.integer64.character()` for reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46332092/2573061), so I've written a workaround function, which calls `bit64::as.integer64()` and then makes some changes to the output:

```
test_string <- c('1234','5678','', 'Help me Stack Overflow')

# illustration of undesired behavior:
library(bit64)
as.integer64(test_string) # returns int64 [1] 1234 5678 0 <NA> without warning

# workaround:    
charToInt64 <- function(s){
  stopifnot( is.character(s) )
  x <- bit64::as.integer64(s)
  # as.integer64("") unexpectedly returns zero without warning.  
  # Overwrite this result to return NA without warning, similar to base as.integer("")
  x[s==""] <- NA_integer64_
  # as.integer64("ABC") unexpectedly returns zero without warning.
  # Overwrite this result to return NA with same coercion warning as base as.integer("ABC")
  bad_strings <- grepl('\\D',s)
  if( any(bad_strings) ){
    warning('NAs introduced by coercion')
    x[bad_strings] <- NA_integer64_  
  }
  x
}

# Demo of workaround -- this behavior mimics base as.integer():
charToInt64(test_string) # returns int64 [1] 1234 5678 <NA> <NA> with warning
charToInt64(head(test_string,-1)) # returns int64 [1] 1234 5678 <NA> without warning
```

So far, so good.

Next, as a learning exercise, I'm trying to override the method `as.integer64.character()` with this workaround.  (I apologize if I'm misusing any OOP terminology in this post, please correct me.)

## What I tried

#### First attempt (doesn't work, infinite recursion)

Naively, I reasoned that since I'm making the namespace explicit when calling the generic function `bit64::as.integer64()` in my workaround function, I should be able to define a  method *with the same name, but in the global environment* that I can call without kicking off infinite recursion.

```
as.integer64.character <- charToInt64 # override method in global environment
as.integer64(test_string) # Error: C stack usage  19922992 is too close to the limit
```

#### Second attempt (works, but I don't understand why)

Replacing the call to the generic function `bit64::as.integer64(s)` with a call to the string method `bit64::as.integer64.character(s)` solves the problem.

```
charToInt64v2 <- function(s){
  stopifnot( is.character(s) )
  x <- bit64::as.integer64.character(s) # this is the only change
  x[s==""] <- NA_integer64_
  bad_strings <- grepl('\\D',s)
  if( any(bad_strings) ){
    warning('NAs introduced by coercion')
    x[bad_strings] <- NA_integer64_  
  }
  x
}
as.integer64.character <- charToInt64v2 
as.integer64(test_string) # works as desired
```

## Recap of question

Why does the second attempt work when the first fails?  What is it about [namespaces](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) and/or [dispatch](http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-dispatch-to-a-method-in-r/) that I don't understand?

Comment: Nice question, couldn't get anywhere with a few minutes of playing around. Maybe it's something to do with the initial `bit64::as.integer64(s)` calling the redefined character method, which has to call the `bit64::as.integer64(s)` again each time? Doesn't look like that should be happening though.

Comment: Your first attempt masks the method with a function that calls the method itself indirectly through the generic. Thus, infinite recursion. The second attempt masks the method with a function that specifically calls the original method. Thus, no recursion.